# How to display cursor where user taps in editor while scrolling up or down in case of long text?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have custom renderer for an editor in xamarin forms. I have added long text in editor. When I open the screen it is showing at the end of text. But if I scroll up text n taps in-between the text then I can see cursor is set where I tapped. Now if I scroll it down then cursor is also moving down instead of steady at the position where I tapped before. So is there any solution for this that cursor should be there at which place user taps even if user scroll up or scroll down the text inside editor in xamarin forms Android?

```
if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                var nativeEditText = (global::Android.Widget.EditText)Control;
                
                nativeEditText.OverScrollMode = OverScrollMode.Always;
                nativeEditText.ScrollBarStyle = ScrollbarStyles.InsideInset;
                nativeEditText.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = true;
                nativeEditText.SetOnTouchListener(new DroidTouchListener());
            
                Control.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = true;                    Control.MovementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod.Instance;
                Control.ScrollBarStyle = Android.Views.ScrollbarStyles.InsideInset;
              
                Android.Content.Res.TypedArray a = Control.Context.Theme.ObtainStyledAttributes(new int[0]);
                InitializeScrollbars(a);
                a.Recycle();
                Control.SetSelection(Control.Length());
            }
```

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: AFAIK, There is no cross-platform way to control this behavior. On each platform (e.g. Android), must write a **Custom Renderer** that subclasses the standard one for the control you are using (is this an `Entry` control?). **If Android's native control for Entry has an option to suppress this behavior,** then in Custom Renderer, set that option when create the native control. Otherwise, You'd have to remember the original `CursorPosition`, override handling of scroll events, and after each scroll, set `CursorPosition` back to its original value. This is an advanced topic, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you... Can you please refer my attached code?

Comment: @Jason - I haven't been writing custom renderers recently - have you? He's shown his custom android code. I don't see any option in Android EditText to do what he wants - do you have any ideas?  I think it may involve [listen for cursor change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5962366/199364) and [OnScrollChanged event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27509507/199364). When a scroll event happens, force the cursor back to where it was. Can you give him more specific advice as to what code is needed?